# Generation of C# files with Google Protocol Fails

Tags: java, c#, c++, protocol-buffers

I am working on a project that uses Java, C# and also C++ applications. To communicate between them I am trying to use Google protocol buffer. I am using following .proto file, which was taken from examples:

```
package tutorial;

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person person = 1;
}
```

I am referring to following tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial

Tutorials for other languages are also there.

I tried following command line arguments for each language:

**Java**:

> C:\ProtoBuf\protoc -I=C:\trash --java_out=C:\trash C:\trash/addressbook.proto

**C++**:

> C:\ProtoBuf\protoc -I=C:\trash --cpp_out=C:\trash C:\trash/addressbook.proto

**C#**:

> C:\ProtoBuf\protoc -I=C:\trash --csharp_out=C:\trash C:\trash/addressbook.proto

Java and C++ compilations work properly even with some warning in case of Java. But I get following output with **C#** :

> --csharp_out: protoc-gen-csharp: The system cannot find the file specified.

I am using this compiler: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protoc-2.6.1-win32.zip

What am I doing wrong here? do I need any other files for C# compilation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know how to gen proto files in c#

1. open visual studio, open nuget command line, type : **Install-Package Google.ProtocolBuffers** , link : [Google.ProtocolBuffers 2.4.1.555](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.ProtocolBuffers/)
2. find Package/Google.ProtocolBuffers.2.4.1.555/tools/ProtoGen.exe
3. use command line, type : **ProtoGen.exe addressbook.proto -output_directory=C:\trash**

I write a python script to gen proto files, gen.py

```
import os, subprocess, threading

def main():
    with open("conf.txt") as file:
        exe = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "..\\Package\\Google.ProtocolBuffers.2.4.1.555\\tools\\ProtoGen.exe")
        out = "-output_directory=%s" % (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "..\\Common\\libs\\protos"))
        def gen(proto):
            subprocess.check_call([exe, os.path.join("protos", proto), out])
        list = []
        for proto in file.read().split(','):
            t = threading.Thread(target = gen, args = (proto, ))
            t.start()
            list.append(t)
        for t in list:
            t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

conf.txt

```
base.proto,test.proto,addressbook.proto
```

Comment: That way emits `Service` generation, how to enable that ?

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to generate C# files using the old version of the protoc

> protoc-2.6.1-win32.zip

C# code generator for both proto2 and proto3 was introduced only in [Version 3.0.0-alpha-3](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0-alpha-3/protoc-3.0.0-alpha-3-win32.zip)

> Introduced two new language implementations (Objective-C, C#) to
>   proto3.

So, download protoc [Version 3.0.0-alpha-3](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0-alpha-3/protoc-3.0.0-alpha-3-win32.zip), install it and call:
`protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --csharp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/your.proto`

**Beware** that started from [Version 3.0.0-beta-1](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta-1) C# code generator only supports generating proto3:

> Proto3 semantics supported; proto2 files are prohibited for C# codegen

Comment: With so many versions/flavors out there, it is hard to pinpoint one particular one. The documentation is also minimal and scattered. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: As of today, the documentation (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial#defining-your-protocol-format) is crappy. The C# tutorial links to a download of the version 2.6.1 which obviously doesn't support C#.

Answer (score 0):

I solved all my problems using / (slash) intead of \ (anti-slash) in all the path.

protoc.exe -I=D:/dev/xyz/projects --csharp_out=d:/temp D:/dev/xyz/projects/messages.proto